# touch event iphone facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile

How can I get jquery click/touch event such tap, click, touchstart etc too work on Facebooks in app browser? Seems impossible!

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.tap.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
  var custom_event = $.support.touch ? "tap" : "click";
});
```

Also tried

```
var custom_event = "touchstart click";
```

And then like so:

```
    $(document).on(custom_event,'#selector',function(){
      // DO STUFF
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha, Weird bug, it was the FB.login that didn't work. Changed to php redirect login for messenger with:

```
$isIosFBMessenger = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'FBAN/MessengerForiOS') !== false) ? true : false;
```